# PHP block is not parsed in html

Tags: php, html

I am writing the following html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    function detectBrowser(){
        if(navigator.appName === "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
            window.open("redirect.html", "_parent");
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="detectBrowser()">
<div class="mainBody">  
<?php
    echo "test";
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But the php block doesn't display test for me. It looks like it is not parsed and I can see the php code in the webpage's source. Any one can tell the problem? 
Thank you

Comment: Is the file saved with extension `.php`? Is your server running PHP?

Comment: Your web server is not configured correctly.

Comment: @jtheman No this is a html file, I want to embed simple php code in it.

Comment: Yes, php is probably not setup/running on the server.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum can you please be a little more clear on the problem? thank you

Comment: Doesn't matter,  change the extension to `.php`. It will still be HTML! But you need to be on a web server that is configured with PHP.

Comment: you need to save it as a .php in order for the php to show

Comment: You should check so you are using a `.php` extension or else the webserver don't know that the file should be parsed as php. If you would like to use another extension like `.html` this can be done by using a `AddType` directive in a `.htaccess` file. Make sure you also show the extension of all files if you are using windows. The file should also be run through a installed server, do you have one?

Comment: my server is running php... its LAMP environment. I am pretty sure I can embed php code in html without changing the suffix of the file. Is there any other possible problem?

Comment: Having html extension for a php file is a very unusual setup. Why won't you just change the extension?

Comment: @KristerAndersson I can try to change the htaccess file and see how it goes

Comment: As Frank commented below. If you have pure html pages, this is needless overhead for them. I would also question why you don't just use the proper extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable parsing of PHP in files with .html extensions in your httpd.conf file.

Look for a line like this and make sure .html is an option.

```
 AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .phtml .html
```

You could probably add it to an .htaccess file in the docroot of you site as well, but I've not tried this personally.

Comment: While this works, it's probably a bad idea (the server probably serves other pure-html files which should not go through the PHP parser).  Changing the extension of the file would be simpler and safer.  If you *really* want .html in your url, you can fake it with a RewriteRule.  Using the "phtml" extension might also be an acceptable compromise.

Answer (score 1):

You could change this in your `.htaccess` file. (if it doesn't exist just create the file (text only) in the same folder as your file)

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

However this would make all static files also go through the PHP parser which is unnecessary.

I would suggest the best solution is to rename the file instead with extension `.php`. Then in your `.htaccess` file you could rewrite just this address, then you will be able to access it with the .html extension anyway.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^myfile.html$ myfile.php
```